# Make jar file copy itself

Tags: java, jar, file-copying

I am trying to make my main executable jar file copy itself to another location.

How can I do this?

Comment: Does it know from an external source where it is, or does it have to find out itself? Also, can you explain in a few words what you're using this for?

Comment: @us2012 No, it does not know where it is. Its kind of hard to explain what this is for, but basically on windows I need to copy it to appdata and on mac to library.

Comment: What is the problem? Do you have difficulties in how to copy with Java or how to find the jar-location? If the jar would copy a different jar - what would be the difference? How is the Program in the jar started?

Comment: @userunknown I know how to copy the file, I need help getting its location.

Comment: This article should help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320542/how-to-get-the-path-of-a-running-jar-file

Comment: @archer Would that also get the name of the running jar file?

Comment: You should adjust the headline of your question to its goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return new File(MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().
 getCodeSource().
 getLocation().
 getURI().
 getPath()).getName();
```

will return a full name

Comment: That seems to work. Do you know if there is a way I can get the name of an EXE that the jar is wrapped in?